# General term of $1,2,3,10,11,12,13, \dots$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

what is the 444th term of the series $1,2,3,10,11,12,13,20,21,22,23,30,31, \dots$

Comment: One resource that comes often useful in these cases is 
The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences http://oeis.org/

Comment: In this particular case, http://www.cleavebooks.co.uk/scol/calnumba.htm may also be useful.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, this is a sequence not a series.
Ok, so how about this...

01,02,03,10,

11,12,13,20,

21,22,23,30,

31,…

Can you see the pattern? :)

If you do observe the pattern, the 444 term would be 1110

Comment: Besides if this is not in base 10, then thats a different approach :)

Answer (score 3):

Based on comments on other answers, you may have guessed that the given information does not determine a unique answer.  As to a hint at what the commenters might be thinking (which would also be my first guess), a number like 12571 is normally taken to mean $1\cdot 10^4+2\cdot 10^3+5\cdot 10^2+7\cdot 10^1+1\cdot 10^0$—that is, we normally interpret strings of digits to be in "base 10" where the digits read from the *right* represent coefficients of successively higher powers of 10.  In base 10, we use digits 0-9.  Your sequence only uses digits 0-3.  Supposing that your sequence were not in base 10, what would this suggest?

Answer (score 2):

What do you think the next 10 terms are? Then how can you express the nth term in terms of n/4 and n mod 4?

Comment: Of course, there is a potential trap if it hasn't been specified that the terms given are numbers in base 10...

Answer (score 1):

By observation, the $n$th term in the sequence may be given by $10\lfloor\frac{n}{4}\rfloor +k$ where $k$ is the remainder when $n$ is divided by $4$ and $\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes the largest integer not larger than $x$. Since $444$ is a multiple of $4$, the $444$th term is simply $1110$.

Comment: But what comes after 33? 100, surely?

Answer (score 1):

`12330` since `444` is `1`$\times4^4+$ `2` $\times4^3+$ `3` $\times4^2+$ `3` $\times4+$ `0` $\times1$.

Comment: Acknowledgements to @TonyK for this.